# Power BI matrix to show unrelated table columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix in Power BI that shows sales and stock information from two tables, by year and region. Third table that contains article IDs and is linked to both tables and used as a slicer. I have also created another table with years and linked it to both tables as well so I could get both sales and stock information on the same matrix.

Sales table contains sales and qty by year and region, while stock table contains stock information only by year.

As a consequence, my matrix shows same stock information for all regions but I would like it to only show it for regions where we have sales (only Asia in example below). Since I do not have stock information by region in stock table but only by year, is there a way to make stock appear in matrix only in regions where we have sales data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using TREATAS function in DAX to connect two unrelated tables.